# AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer work with Internet streamed mp3

Tags: ios, mp3, converters

I am currently streaming mp3 audio through the Internet. I am using AudioFileStream to parse the mp3 steam 
comes through a CFReadStreamRef, decode the mp3 using AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer and copy the converted PCM 
data into a ring buffer and finally play the PCM using RemoteIO.

The problem I am currently facing is the AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer always returns 0 (no error) but the conversion 
result seems incorrect. In details, I can notice,

A. The UInt32 *ioOutputDataPacketSize keeps the same value I sent in.

B. The convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize always been set to the size of the outputbuffer (doesn't matter how big the buffer is).

C. I can only hear clicking noise with the output data.

Below is my procedures for rendering the audio. 
The same procedure works for my Audio queue implementation so I believe 
I didn't something wrong in either the place I invoking the AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer or the callback of AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer.

I have been stuck on this issue for a long time. Any help will be highly appreciated.

1. Open a AudioFileStream.

   // create an audio file stream parser
   AudioFileTypeID fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMP3Type;
   AudioFileStreamOpen(self, MyPropertyListenerProc, MyPacketsProc, fileTypeHint, &audioFileStream);
2. Handle the parsed data in the callback function ("MyPacketsProc").

   void MyPacketsProc(void * inClientData,
                      UInt32 inNumberBytes,
                      UInt32 inNumberPackets,
                      const void * inInputData,
                      AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions)
   {
   @synchronized(self)
       {
           // Init the audio converter.
           if (!audioConverter)
               AudioConverterNew(&asbd, &asbd_out, &audioConverter);

   ```
       struct mp3Data mSettings;
       memset(&mSettings, 0, sizeof(mSettings));


       UInt32 packetsPerBuffer = 0;
       UInt32 outputBufferSize = 1024 * 32; // 32 KB is a good starting point.
       UInt32 sizePerPacket = asbd.mBytesPerPacket;


       // Calculate the size per buffer.
       // Variable Bit Rate Data.
       if (sizePerPacket == 0)
       {
           UInt32 size = sizeof(sizePerPacket);
           AudioConverterGetProperty(audioConverter, kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize, &size, &sizePerPacket);

           if (sizePerPacket > outputBufferSize)
               outputBufferSize = sizePerPacket;

           packetsPerBuffer = outputBufferSize / sizePerPacket;
       }
       //CBR
       else
           packetsPerBuffer = outputBufferSize / sizePerPacket;



       // Prepare the input data for the callback.
       mSettings.inputBuffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberBytes;
       mSettings.inputBuffer.mData = (void *)inInputData;
       mSettings.inputBuffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
       mSettings.numberPackets = inNumberPackets;
       mSettings.packetDescription = inPacketDescriptions;


       // Set up our output buffers
       UInt8 * outputBuffer = (UInt8*)malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * outputBufferSize);
       memset(outputBuffer, 0, outputBufferSize);


       // describe output data buffers into which we can receive data.
       AudioBufferList convertedData;
       convertedData.mNumberBuffers = 1;
       convertedData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
       convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = outputBufferSize;
       convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData = outputBuffer;

       // Convert.
       UInt32 ioOutputDataPackets = packetsPerBuffer;
       OSStatus result = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverter,                
                                                         converterComplexInputDataProc, 
                                                         &mSettings,                          
                                                         &ioOutputDataPackets,          
                                                         &convertedData,            
                                                         NULL                 
                                                         );

       // Enqueue the ouput pcm data.
       TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&m_pcmBuffer, convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData, convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
       free(outputBuffer);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Feed the audio converter from its callback function ("converterComplexInputDataProc").

OSStatus converterComplexInputDataProc(AudioConverterRef inAudioConverter,
                                       UInt32* ioNumberDataPackets,
                                       AudioBufferList* ioData,
                                       AudioStreamPacketDescription** ioDataPacketDescription,
                                       void* inUserData)
{
    struct mp3Data *THIS = (struct mp3Data*) inUserData;

```
if (THIS->inputBuffer.mDataByteSize > 0)
{
    *ioNumberDataPackets = THIS->numberPackets;
    ioData->mNumberBuffers = 1;
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = THIS->inputBuffer.mDataByteSize;
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mData = THIS->inputBuffer.mData;
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;

    if (ioDataPacketDescription)
        *ioDataPacketDescription = THIS->packetDescription;
}
else
    *ioDataPacketDescription = 0;

return 0;
```

}

1. Playback using the RemoteIO component.
2. The input and output AudioStreamBasicDescription.

**Input:**

Sample Rate:              16000
Format ID:                 .mp3

Format Flags:                 0

Bytes per Packet:             0

Frames per Packet:          576

Bytes per Frame:              0

Channels per Frame:           1

Bits per Channel:             0

**output:**

Sample Rate:              44100

Format ID:                 lpcm

Format Flags:              3116

Bytes per Packet:             4

Frames per Packet:            1

Bytes per Frame:              4

Channels per Frame:           1

Bits per Channel:            32

Comment: did you fix this? I can hear some noise in my audio only using iphone 6

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm looking to do the same thing.